# How to use paging3 library in jetpack compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-paging-3

I'm trying to use the paging library for my project but it doesn't seem to work. I'll leave my classes below to see if anyone can help me.

My FrutasViewModel:

```
class FrutasViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private lateinit var content: Flow<PagingData<CategoryProductQueryRequest>>
    var stateStatus =
        MutableStateFlow<StateStatus<Flow<PagingData<CategoryProductQueryRequest>>>>(StateStatus.Start)
    val managedGrpc = ManagedGrpc()
    private var stubCategoryProductQuery: CategoryProductQueryGrpc.CategoryProductQueryStub

    init {
        managedGrpc.inicializar("categoryproduct")
        stubCategoryProductQuery = CategoryProductQueryGrpc.newStub(managedGrpc.canal)

    }

    fun openChannel() {
        if (managedGrpc.canal.isShutdown) {
            managedGrpc.inicializar("categoryproduct")
            stubCategoryProductQuery = CategoryProductQueryGrpc.newStub(managedGrpc.canal)
        }
    }

    fun getFrutas(id: Int?): Flow<PagingData<CategoryProductQueryRequest>> {
        stateStatus.value = StateStatus.Loading
        try {

            content = getFrutasPage(id).cachedIn(viewModelScope)
            stateStatus.value = StateStatus.Success(content)

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            stateStatus.value = StateStatus.Failure(errorMessage = e.localizedMessage!!)
        }
        return content
    }


    private fun getFrutasPage(id: Int?): Flow<PagingData<CategoryProductQueryRequest>> {
        return Pager(
            config = PagingConfig(
                pageSize = 10,
                enablePlaceholders = false
            ),
            pagingSourceFactory = {
                ShoppingDataSource(
                    id = id,
                    stub = stubCategoryProductQuery,
                    managedGrpc = managedGrpc
                )
            }
        ).flow
    }
}
```

My ShoppingDataSource:

```
class ShoppingDataSource(
    private val id:Int?,
    private var stub: CategoryProductQueryGrpc.CategoryProductQueryStub,
    private var managedGrpc : ManagedGrpc
) : PagingSource<Int, CategoryProductQueryRequest>() {
    private var itens: CategoryQueryResponse? = null
    private var requestObserver: StreamObserver<CategoryQueryRequest>?=null
    private val responseObserver = object : StreamObserver<CategoryQueryResponse> {
        override fun onNext(response: CategoryQueryResponse) {
            itens =CategoryQueryResponse.newBuilder()
                .setCount(response.count)
                .setNextPage(response.nextPage)
                .setPrevPage(response.prevPage)
                .addAllResults(response.resultsList)
                .setPages(response.pages).build()

        }

        override fun onError(t: Throwable?) {
            val status: Status = Status.fromThrowable(t)
            Log.e("Failed",status.description!!)
            finishLatch.countDown()
        }

        override fun onCompleted() {
            finishLatch.countDown()
        }
    }
    val finishLatch = CountDownLatch(1)

    // Função para fechar o canal gRPC
    private fun closeCanal() {
        if (!managedGrpc.canal.isShutdown) {
            managedGrpc.canal.shutdown()
        }
    }

    override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, CategoryProductQueryRequest> {

        // Retrofit calls that return the body type throw either IOException for network
        // failures, or HttpException for any non-2xx HTTP status codes. This code reports all
        // errors to the UI, but you can inspect/wrap the exceptions to provide more context.
        return try {
            // Key may be null during a refresh, if no explicit key is passed into Pager
            // construction. Use 0 as default, because our API is indexed started at index 0
            val pageNumber = params.key ?: 0

            // Suspending network load via Retrofit. This doesn't need to be wrapped in a
            // withContext(Dispatcher.IO) { ... } block since Retrofit's Coroutine
            // CallAdapter dispatches on a worker thread.

            requestObserver =stub.getCategoryProduct(responseObserver)
            try {
               val request= CategoryQueryRequest.newBuilder()
                        .setData(id!!.toLong())
                        .setPageNum(pageNumber)
                        .build()
                requestObserver?.onNext(request)

                withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                    finishLatch.await(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                }

            } catch (e: RuntimeException) {
                requestObserver?.onError(e)
                Log.e("ERRO",e.message!!)
            }

            // Since 0 is the lowest page number, return null to signify no more pages should
            // be loaded before it.
            val prevKey = if (pageNumber > 1) pageNumber - 1 else null

            // This API defines that it's out of data when a page returns empty. When out of
            // data, we return `null` to signify no more pages should be loaded
            val nextKey = if (pageNumber+1>itens!!.pages) null else pageNumber+1

            if(nextKey==null){
                requestObserver?.onCompleted()
                closeCanal()
            }

            LoadResult.Page(
                    data = itens!!.resultsList,
                    prevKey = prevKey,
                    nextKey = nextKey
            )


        } catch (e: IOException) {
            closeCanal()
            LoadResult.Error(e)
        } catch (e: HttpException) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 34) {
                closeCanal()
                LoadResult.Error(e)
            } else {
                closeCanal()
               TODO("VERSION.SDK_INT < 34")
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getRefreshKey(state: PagingState<Int, CategoryProductQueryRequest>): Int? {
        return state.anchorPosition?.let {
            state.closestPageToPosition(it)?.prevKey?.plus(1)
                ?: state.closestPageToPosition(it)?.nextKey?.minus(1)
        }
    }


}
```

My class StateStatus:

```
sealed class StateStatus<out T> where T : Any? {
    object Start : StateStatus<Nothing>()

    object Loading : StateStatus<Nothing>()

    data class Success<T>(val data: T) : StateStatus<T>()

    data class Failure(val errorMessage: String) : StateStatus<Nothing>()
}
```

And finally my code calls the viewmodel:

```
LaunchedEffect(Unit){
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        // Operações de entrada/saída (ex: chamadas de rede) aqui
            viewModel.getFrutas(id, without)
    }

}

val states by viewModel.stateStatus.collectAsState()

when (states) {
    is StateStatus.Start -> {

    }
    StateStatus.Loading -> {
        helpers.LoadingComponent()
    }
    is StateStatus.Failure -> {
        Box(contentAlignment = Alignment.Center, modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.error),fontSize = 16.sp)
        }
    }
    is StateStatus.Success -> {
        list =  (states as StateStatus.Success).data.collectAsLazyPagingItems()
        images = imgs
        idFrutas = id
        modelFrutas=viewModel

        
            LazyColumn(
                state = rememberLazyListState(),

                ) {
                items(
                    count = list.itemCount,
                    key = list.itemKey(),
                    contentType = list.itemContentType()
                )
                { index ->
                    val item = list[index]


                    if (item != null) {

                        var visible by rememberSaveable(index) {
                            mutableStateOf(true)
                        }

                        ShowCategories(item)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Version:

> ```
> implementation("androidx.paging:paging-compose:3.2.1")
> implementation("androidx.paging:paging-runtime-ktx:3.2.1")
> ```

When I execute the project and see the list on my cell phone, it slows down, does anyone know how to help me fix it?